# How to build a interop dll from the UIAutomationClient.dll

Tags: dll, interop, ui-automation

I want to create / build a interop dll from the existing UIAutomationClient.dll Version 4.0..
I tried to use the TlbImp.exe with the following command:

```
TlbImp.exe path\UIAutomationClient.dll out:Interop.UIAutomationClient.dll
```

But i'm getting the following error message:

> Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Type Library to Assembly Converter
>   4.0.4013 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> TlbImp : error TI0000 : The input file
>   'C:\Users\patrick\Desktop\UIAutomationCli ent.dll' is not a valid type
>   library.

Is there another way to create the interop dll or a solution to this error ?

Comment: What is "UIAutomation.dll" ?

Comment: Its the dll which you need to use the Mircosoft UI Automation Framework, VS->Add reference->.NEt->UIAutomationClient.dll but i need the Intertop of this dll

Comment: If you are talking about UIAutomationClient.dll and not UIAutomation.dll then please fix your question first. UIAutomationClient is already a .NET assembly.

Comment: yeah sorry, i meant the UIAutomationClient.dll #fixed

Comment: So it's already managed. You don't have to create any interop on it.

Comment: Using the interop i only want to use the unmanged com communication interfaces of the interop.dll, the UIAutomationClient.dll contains implementations which are fatal for the performance (40sec.+ to read 100cells of a table, with the intertop.dll only ~2sec.). I already got from a friend a intertop.automationclient.dll but its build from the version 2.0, i need the 4.0 version. Sadly he is the next 3 weeks on vacation so i can't ask him how he had done it the last time.

Comment: So you probably mean UIAutomationCore.dll, not UIAutomationClient.dll. Running TLBIMP on UIAutomationCore.dll will create a UIAutomationClient.dll (that has nothing to do with the .NET one...)

Comment: Ah ok, it works now fine. A little bit confussing with the names. Could you post this as a answer, so that i can accept it ? Thanks

Comment: You should accept Hans' answer as it already speaks about the TLBIMP command in the 2nd part (I don't personally have this dll in VS directory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is present on your machine in the `Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies` subdirectory of your VS install directory.  It carries a Microsoft copyright and is not part of the redistributable files so just making a copy is a bit iffy, even though it doesn't contain any code.

You can create your own by running Tlbimp.exe on c:\windows\syswow64\uiautomationcore.dll.  Use system32 on a 32-bit operating system.

You ought to wonder a bit about the reason you have a dependency on it.