# Cannot retrieve the pattern for a control when using the System.WindowsAutomation library

Tags: winforms, automation, ui-automation

I am trying to automate WinForms app using the `System.Windows.Automation`, I am able to retrieve the element (tab item)

`var tab = window.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Tab));`

but not able to get the pattern to select it (`SelectionItemPattern`). Here's is the list of patterns and their availability for that element (i.e. none):

`Patterns for ControlType.TabItem:
Is DockPatternIdentifiers.Pattern available: no
Is ExpandCollapsePatternIdentifiers.Pattern available: no
Is GridItemPatternIdentifiers.Pattern available: no
Is GridPatternIdentifiers.Pattern available: no
Is InvokePatternIdentifiers.Pattern available: no
Is ItemContainerPatternIdentifiers.Pattern available: no
Is MultipleViewPatternIdentifiers.Pattern available: no
Is RangeValuePatternIdentifiers.Pattern available: no
Is ScrollItemPatternIdentifiers.Pattern available: no
Is ScrollPatternIdentifiers.Pattern available: no
Is SelectionItemPatternIdentifiers.Pattern available: no <------------
Is SelectionPatternIdentifiers.Pattern available: no
Is SynchronizedInputPatternIdentifiers.Pattern available: no
Is TableItemPatternIdentifiers.Pattern available: no
Is TablePatternIdentifiers.Pattern available: no
Is TextPatternIdentifiers.Pattern available: no
Is TogglePatternIdentifiers.Pattern available: no
Is TransformPatternIdentifiers.Pattern available: no
Is ValuePatternIdentifiers.Pattern available: no
Is VirtualizedItemPatternIdentifiers.Pattern available: no
Is WindowPatternIdentifiers.Pattern available: no`

When I inspect the application with `inspect.exe` or `VisualUIAVerifyNative.exe` I can see that the pattern is there and available, output from `inspect.exe`:

`IsAnnotationPatternAvailable:    false
IsDragPatternAvailable: false
IsDockPatternAvailable: false
IsDropTargetPatternAvailable:   false
IsExpandCollapsePatternAvailable:   false
IsGridItemPatternAvailable: false
IsGridPatternAvailable: false
IsInvokePatternAvailable:   false
IsItemContainerPatternAvailable:    false
IsLegacyIAccessiblePatternAvailable:    true
IsMultipleViewPatternAvailable: false
IsObjectModelPatternAvailable:  false
IsRangeValuePatternAvailable:   false
IsScrollItemPatternAvailable:   false
IsScrollPatternAvailable:   false
IsSelectionItemPatternAvailable:    true <---------------------------------
IsSelectionPatternAvailable:    false
IsSpreadsheetItemPatternAvailable:  false
IsSpreadsheetPatternAvailable:  false
IsStylesPatternAvailable:   false
IsSynchronizedInputPatternAvailable:    false
IsTableItemPatternAvailable:    false
IsTablePatternAvailable:    false
IsTextChildPatternAvailable:    false
IsTextEditPatternAvailable: false
IsTextPatternAvailable: false
IsTextPattern2Available:    false
IsTogglePatternAvailable:   false
IsTransformPatternAvailable:    false
IsTransform2PatternAvailable:   false
IsValuePatternAvailable:    false
IsVirtualizedItemPatternAvailable:  false
IsWindowPatternAvailable:   false`

It works fine for a small app built using pure WinForms controls. In this case the app is built using 3rd party components. My conclusion is that the problem in the way the automation is implemented in those controls.

So is the pattern really available? Is `inspect.exe` getting the using through a different API?

I can run the accessibility tests in `VisualUIAVerifyNative` (namely `Pattern Tests` > `Priority 3 Tests` > `Select.1.4` test) to select the tab. Or I can select by executing the command in the property grid (`Patterns` > `SelectionItemPattern` > `Select`).

Looks like I am missing something important in my C# code.

Can anybody help? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution - instead of referencing the `System.Windows.Automation.dll` I am now referencing `Interop.UIAutomationClient.dll`. This DLL is part of the UIAutomationVerify distribution or can be generated using `TlbImp.exe` (see [How to build a interop dll from the UIAutomationClient.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18079477/how-to-build-a-interop-dll-from-the-uiautomationclient-dll)).